# R: Summation of Single Column Based on Conditions

Tags: r

I have a dataset that has (with the help of this site) created a count based on 3 instances:

1. Number of `Plans` where `Coins` is greater than 20
2. Number of `Plans` where `Coins` is equal to 20
3. Number of `Plans` where `Coins` is less than 20

Here's a sample from the much larger dataset

```
Plan    Year   Coins   Copay   Enrollment
  A     2018     20      10       200
  B     2014     15       5       100
  C     2012     30       0        50
  D     2017     30      10       350
  E     2018     5       10       400
  F     2018     20       0       150
  G     2018     20       0       200
  H     2016     20      10       800
  I     2014     10       3       250
  J     2017     20       7       550
```

This was achieved through:

```
df %>%
   group_by(grp = case_when(Coins < 20 ~ 'grp1', Coins ==20 ~ 'grp2', TRUE ~ 'grp3')) %>%
   summarise(Plan = toString(unique(Plan)), prop = n()) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

To get:

1. C, D - 2
2. A, F, G, H, J - 5
3. B, E, I - 3

I would now like to involve the `Enrollment` column and sum based on the three conditions above. Thus, I would like to achieve the following counts:

1. 400 (50+350)
2. 1900 (200+150+200+800+550)
3. 750 (100+400+250)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `counts = sum(Enrollment)` summary prior to `ungroup`ing.

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    group_by(grp = case_when(Coins < 20 ~ 'grp1', Coins ==20 ~ 'grp2', TRUE ~ 'grp3')) %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%
    summarise(
        Plan = toString(unique(Plan)),
        prop = n(),
        counts = sum(Enrollment)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-grp);
## A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Plan           prop counts
#  <chr>         <int>  <int>
#1 B, E, I           3    750
#2 A, F, G, H, J     5   1900
#3 C, D              2    400
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Plan    Year   Coins   Copay   Enrollment
  A     2018     20      10       200
  B     2014     15       5       100
  C     2012     30       0        50
  D     2017     30      10       350
  E     2018     5       10       400
  F     2018     20       0       150
  G     2018     20       0       200
  H     2016     20      10       800
  I     2014     10       3       250
  J     2017     20       7       550", header = T)
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much - the answer was right in front of me (check my username). One more question: I am currently getting a result that looks something like this: 6.33e5 - how can I return an exact value?

Comment: @NewToThisRThing I believe this is just how `tibble` formats large number when printing; the value is still exact. You can add `%>% as.data.frame()` at the end of your `magrittr` chain to print values in a "`data.frame` way".